# Как B возвести в квадрат

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
D = input("Какое действие (Дискриминант: D)")


A1 = int(input ("Введите A:") )
B1 = int(input ("Введите B:") )
С1 = int(input ("Введите С:") )

if D == "D":
    (B1**)+(-4)*A1*C1=D
    Print( "Дискриминант= "+str(D))
```

Comment: D = (B1**2)-4*A1*C1

Comment: NameError: name 'C1' is not defined

Comment: Проверьте что у Вас там не русская С где то :)

Comment: Да С была русская и print c большой буквы. А так все заработало, спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

**Возведение в степень:**

`print(6 ** 2)`  # Возводим число 6 в степень 2. Результат - 36